# Reading decimal dot in ADODB select from csv file

Tags: excel, vba, format, adodb

I have created user formula with an ADODB connection in Excel VBA to read the fields from a csv file. Everything works great but one thing: when the field has decimals (the decimal character is "."), the result from the connection is the whole figure without the dot. For example, if the field contains 10.38, the result would be 1038.

The separator for the .csv file is ";", and I've tried a schema.ini approach, specifying the separator and the type of data for the specific field that contains decimals.

The relevant vba code:

```
Dim xlcon As ADODB.Connection
Dim xlrs As ADODB.Recordset
Set xlcon = New ADODB.Connection
Set xlrs = New ADODB.Recordset
xlcon.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
xlcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & currentDataFilePath & ";" & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;"""
xlcon.Open
MyQuery = "SELECT " & myep & " AS DATO FROM [" & currentDataFileName & ".csv] WHERE ENT=" & ent & " AND FECHA='" & myfc & "'"
On Error GoTo misErrores
Set xlrs = xlcon.Execute(MyQuery)
resultado = xlrs.Fields(0)
xlrs.Close
Set xlrs = Nothing
xlcon.Close
Set xlcon = Nothing
Ep = resultado
```

The schema.ini file:

```
[2175G.csv]
ColNameHeader = True
Format=Delimited(;)
col4="x1" Double
```

The file has around 100 different fields, but I think I have to specify the type only for the ones that contain decimals. In this case, only the field named "x1", that is located in the 4th place contains decimals. Unfortunately, this does not work. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the CSV file contains values with a dot as decimal separator, like `12.34`, but the regional settings on the client running this program is set to comma as decimal separator, is that correct?

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017) you can specify the decimal separator in the schema.ini file, so try something like this:

```
[2175G.csv]
ColNameHeader = True
Format=Delimited(;)
DecimalSymbol=.
col4="x1" Double
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try another driver

```vb
Dim xlcon As ADODB.Connection
Dim currentDataFilePath As String

xlcon.Open "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)" & _
      ";Dbq=" & currentDataFilePath  & _
      ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"
```

Comment: I don't think it has nothing to do withe the driver. Nevertheless, I've tried and it does not work even for the fields that does not have decimals.